# for文を使った計算結果をすべてデータフレームに表示したいです。

Tags: python, python3

グリッドサーチを使ってチューニングを行っています。以下のコードで計算結果を得ました。

```
for i in range(1,7):
  param_grid = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(i,),(i,i),(i,i,i)]}

  grid_search = GridSearchCV(MLPClassifier(random_state=0), param_grid, cv=5)
  grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
  cvres = grid_search.cv_results_
  for score, params in zip(cvres['mean_test_score'], cvres['params']):
    print(score,params)
```

以上より得られた結果を，さらにデータフレームしたく，以下のコードを実行しました。

```
  df_bst_rs = pd.DataFrame({'rank_test_score':cvres['rank_test_score'],'mean_test_score':cvres['mean_test_score']})
  df_rs_cv_results = pd.DataFrame(cvres['params'])
  df_bst_rs = pd.concat([df_bst_rs, df_rs_cv_results], axis=1)
  df_bst_rs.sort_values('rank_test_score', inplace=True)

  pd.set_option("display.max_rows",len(df_bst_rs))
  df_bst_rs
```

しかし，これではi=6のときの結果しかデータフレームで表示することができません。
i=1~6すべての結果を表示するためには，どのようにすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: 提示された質問内容だけだと、助言・回答を得るには情報が不足している感じです。これらのヘルプ記事を参考に、詳細な内容を追記してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 前半のコードと後半のコードの関係が不明。もしも前半のコードで 1〜6 までの処理を行った後に, 改めて後半のコード実行したなら 6の処理しか行われないでしょう (Jupyterとかで実行したなら `i` は `6`のままになってるはずなので)